# Under no load condition,what will be the angle between the induced voltage and the supply voltage in synchronous motor?

Tags: synchronous-motor

Can anyone explain what will be the angle between induced voltage and supply voltage in synchronous voltage under no load condition?

Answer (score 1):

It is the induced current you should examine and the motor is more inductive now with no load so it lags almost 90deg.   The Back EMF reduces this current with no load.

For more details with field current see https://circuitglobe.com/synchronous-impedance-method.html